How to disable auto routing in CakePHP?
In CakePHP, the routing works based on controller and action but I wanted to disable the auto-routing based on controller and action on URL so that the defined routes can only be accessible.
For Example: A UserController having a method called login can be accessible with hostname/controller/action (hostname/user/login) which I wanted to block.
Expectation: The same URL can be accessible only when the routes are defined (hostname/login).

comment the line in the routes.php for fallback.
$builder->fallbacks();
